# how to query if a column is named as a keyword in dolphindb?

Tags: database, dolphindb

had a table contains a column named true in pic below
[enter image description here][1]

and code like

```py
select true from t
```

error : Syntax Error: [line #1] A table column [1] must be assigned a valid name.

why?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6lna.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sql function to query. The code is as follows:

```py
sql(sqlCol("true"), t).eval()
```